# Blend file size increase after append despite deleting the original geometry

Tags: mesh, linked-data, append, saving

I made a brick building, and wanted to make sections of the brick wall to help streamline buildings. I started with 1 segment, and added a skinny cube to act as the mortar. This file when saved was 7 mb. Instead of recreating the setup for each new wall segment, I deleted the brick segment for section 001 and use append to bring in the next section. I repeated this for the next sections (10 in all) with the final file size for section 10 being 80 MB. [image] I have added an image for reference, but have no idea why they are increasing each time. It clearly has something to do with append, but there are no more objects in any file that is not in the other, smaller, original file. Any suggestions?

Edit:
A suggestion of mesh data was given but I do not know much about that. The object seems gone but there must be something leftover after deleting old geometry, whether a reference to the deleted stuff or leftover material data etc I am not sure. I can upload a couple of the blend files but do not know how on here. Can someone help me get these file sizes down please?

Comment: The blend file can store the mesh data without objects. If you pick your 80MB file in the append menu and choose mesh, can you see the meshes of the deleted objects?

Comment: I am not sure. i don't see anything but might not be looking in the right area. I am happy to upload section 2 and section 10 so the smallest can be compared with the biggest. I am not sure how to upload though